# Exact bounds for the Median of the Hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function, median

I am wondering if anybody knows good exact bounds for the Median of a Hypergeometric distribution:

$$
X \sim \text{Hypergeometric}(N,K,n)
$$

One exact bound could be given by exploiting the [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Inequality_relating_means_and_medians) between Mean, Median and Standard Deviation.

Another direction might be the Binomial approximation of Hyperbolic distribution, because there is an explicit bound for the [Median of a Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Median).
Further, there are [explicit bounds](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ekuensch/papers/hypergeom.pdf) for the Total variation distance between Hypergeometric and Binomial distributions.
These might be combined to a tighter bound than one obtained by Mean and Standard Deviation.

Is anybody aware of a formula or reference that would yield a tight explicit expression for such bounds?